# Print displayed from the browser

Tags: pdf, browser, printing

I have users that basically love PDFs since they know the users will get a page that will look like they expect.  I want to have the users just create a web page and print it.  Is there a way I can guarantee them what the user will get?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you actually serve PDFs, there's no way to *guarantee* a printed web page will always look exactly the same. However, you usually don't need 100% accuracy. Most users only care that the page is readable and looks clean (no one wants reams of navigation links and ads, for instance). You can be reasonably sure of achieving these two goals by implementing a print stylesheet, and/or by using print CSS media queries.

This is one of the better articles I've found on the topic: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/